# How to find the data length code CAN frame?

Tags: can

Question written as its I want to find the data length code of the CAN data frame.

In our textbook we are given a formula in picture which bits do I have to include to this formula:

[image]

Which bits do I have to include to this formula?

For example data frame is:

[image]

Comment: That's a silly formula, all it does is just describes how to read any binary number... so your question boils down to "what is a binary number". Very basic stuff that one is supposed to study before taking one's very first programming beginner class. The DLC is simply a binary value of 4 bits, expressing a length between 0 and 8 bytes (classic CAN).

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like homework we will take the "teach a person to fish" approach:

The DLC field is 4 bits long and encodes the length of the payload as an integer, valid values being from 0 to 8. Here's an image from wikipedia detailing the assignment of bits in the header:

[image: wikipedia can frame]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Frames

Note that your bit positions are prior to any bit stuffing that's required, whereas the image is the stuffed "on the wire" message. More about bit stuffing is also found on the wikipedia page here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Bit_stuffing

Answer (score 1):

Your example frame is in standard format: 11-bit identifier.  You know this because the IDE bit is zero.

[image]

Breaking down the data stream, from left to right, you have

- 0 - Start of frame
- 00000110010 - Identifier
- 0 - RTR (Remote request)
- 0 - IDE (Identifier Extension)
- 0 - r0 (reserved)
- 0010 - DLC (data length code)
- 00101111 - first data byte

followed by the next data byte.  The DLC in this case is 2, indicating that there are 2 bytes of data in this message.

Had this been an extended format frame (IDE=1), the DLC would be a little further down in the bitstream:

[image]

The CAN spec is readily available online.
(Images are from the Bosch CAN Specification 2.0)

Comment: This would have been correct if not for bit stuffing. A CAN frame cannot look like the binary goo in the question, because it only allows 5 consecutive bits with the same value. Since there are 6 consecutive zeroes etc in the binary goo, it's not a valid frame.

Comment: @Lundin  Stuff bits are inserted and deleted automatically by hardware to maintain synchronization during transmission.  They are not considered to be part of the message.  Messages are pushed to and pulled from mailboxes without stuff bits; they don't exist above the lowest hardware level and are transparent to the user.  The example message above clearly is without stuff bits, so that is how I answered the question. But your point is valid; If you actually probe the CANHI/CANLO signals, you would see stuff bits

Comment: You wouldn't need to manually decode anything once it has passed the controller. Everything will be placed in tidy registers.

Answer (score 0):

How to actually decode the data given:

0 = start of frame
0000 = start of 11 bit identifier
0 = bit stuffing error

And there you can stop your decoding attempts, it's an invalid CAN frame and so it can't be decoded.

The *only* reason why you would ever want to decode CAN frames manually like this is when reading them through an oscilloscope and in that case you have to take bit stuffing in account.